# Set multple small image in Javascript (Like carousel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, material-design

I am using Materialize design, Jquery and javascript. I want to implement set multiple images in one row and auto move to particular direction. Right now i am using 3d effect carousel in Materialize design. But it is not works fine. When i put anchor tag(put redirect link) then it will stuck (some time ).

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
  dist: 0,
  shift: 0,
  padding: 20,
  interval: 100
});
```

```css
.carousel .carousel-item {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div class="carousel">
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1">
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2">
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3">
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4">
  </a>


  <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5">
  </a>

</div>
```

I want to implement like app.
http://www.jqueryrain.com/?Q5dad1oS

I want to display multiple small image. But i don't want to use any plugin. Because i don't want increase size of page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find answer to my question.
I have implemented carousel without using any plugin. It use plain javascript or jquery.

```js
var firstval = 0;

function Carousel() {
    firstval += 2;
    parent = document.getElementById('container');
    parent.style.left = "-" + firstval + "px";
    if (!(firstval % 150)) {
        setTimeout(Carousel, 3000);
        firstval = 0;
        var firstChild = parent.firstElementChild;
        parent.appendChild(firstChild);
        parent.style.left= 0;
        return;
    }
    runCarousel = setTimeout(Carousel, 10);
}
Carousel();
```

```css
        #wrapper {
            position: relative;
            width: 450px;
            height: 150px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #container {
            position: absolute;
            width: 450px;
            height: 150px;
        }
        .child {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            padding-top: 35px;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 60px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div  class="child"><img width="100" src="https://d2z4fd79oscvvx.cloudfront.net/0020232_chocolate_cream_gateaux_cake_320.jpeg"> </div>
        <div  class="child"><img width="100" src="https://d2z4fd79oscvvx.cloudfront.net/0018904_50_red_roses_in_vase_320.jpeg"> </div>
        <div  class="child"><img width="100" src="https://d2z4fd79oscvvx.cloudfront.net/0020232_chocolate_cream_gateaux_cake_320.jpeg"> </div>
 <div  class="child"><img width="100" src="https://d2z4fd79oscvvx.cloudfront.net/0020232_chocolate_cream_gateaux_cake_320.jpeg"> </div>
    <div  class="child"><img width="100" src="https://d2z4fd79oscvvx.cloudfront.net/0018904_50_red_roses_in_vase_320.jpeg"> </div>
    <div  class="child"><img width="100" src="https://d2z4fd79oscvvx.cloudfront.net/0020232_chocolate_cream_gateaux_cake_320.jpeg"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean marquee?

Please refer: http://download.remysharp.com/marquee.html

Have a few different ways to do that, either by CSS or js.

Comment: can you create any Jsfiddle and working example with multiple images..Because this not aligned properly.

Comment: http://log.vieron.net/articles/pure-css-infinite-scrolling-image-marquee/, here provided tutorial and demo